# Sending plain text as POST body causes issue in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm making POST request to my backend, but i'm getting a 400 only using retrofit.
I dug more into the issue and realized since my POST body is a plain string (not JSON), whenever I have double quote, it puts a back slash behind it and then sends the request. Here is the call:

```
@POST("/endpoint")
Observable<Result<MyResponse>> myApiCall(@Body String body);
```

I did some research and people suggested that I need to add a StringConverterFactory, but that didn't help (I followed this link: [String converter factory](https://gist.github.com/tomkoptel/35ea8dca7fca040d63f3) )

I think that link in retrofit github page is outdated!

Comment: Are you trying to send POST data in form format i.e. of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ..

```
@POST("/endpoint")
Observable<Result<MyResponse>> myApiCall(@Body RequestBody body);

RequestBody body= RequestBody.create(MyRequest.create("data"));

public abstract class StringRequestBody extends RequestBody {

        public static RequestBody create(String content) {
            MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/plain");
            Charset charset = Util.UTF_8;
            if (contentType != null) {
                charset = contentType.charset();
                if (charset == null) {
                    charset = Util.UTF_8;
                    contentType = MediaType.parse(contentType + "; charset=utf-8");
                }
            }
            byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(charset);
            return create(contentType, bytes);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, I guess this solution works, but it's really not convenient, cause I have to do that RequestBody thing every time I want to use the API!

Comment: Then why don't you create a wrapper over RequestBody and fix your contentType , that would simplify things . Please check the edit and let me know if have anymore issue .

Comment: Yeah, this also look like the previous one, though it might look nicer. My issue with this solution is that I'm passing a RequestBody to "myApiCall" rather than a String. I appreciate your help tho.

Comment: @Code_Life where i can implement this code snippet? i read the gist mentioned in question, but it gives me errors for "implement" and suggest "extends"

Comment: Thanks A lot, you saved my day :)

Answer (score -1):

if anyone encouner this issue, to send json body string without POJO Model class then you need to declare a method in your RetrofitService:

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @POST("path")
    Call<ResponseBody> update(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
}
```

Next you need to create a RequestBody and Call object:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://somedomain.com").build();
    RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    
    String strRequestBody = "body";
    //use text/json for Json data string, or use text/plain for any other text
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/json"), bodyTextStringJsonValue);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitService.update(requestBody);
```

[Reference answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332684/7048025)

Answer (score -2):

Try This :

@POST("endpoint")
Observable> myApiCall(@Body String body);

Comment: Observable> is this java?