# How to Post Raw Json Object in Android (Java) using Retrofit without POJO class

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

There are two activities, Activity A and Activity B

I made an API call in activity A and converted the `JsonObject` into string for my further use, now I again converted it to `JsonObject` using `JsonParser.parseString(JsonObject which was converted to string).getAsJsonObject();`

Now I made a Post API Call to send it same as `Jsonobject` to server Using retrofit 2.9.0 for some reason it's converted it to string when sent it
By the way, I Have already tried 10-15 Stack Overflow examples but none worked till now. So if you have personally sent raw `jsonobject` to post API, your help is much appreciated!

Here is sample JsonObject data:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "care_of": "S/O: Kaleen Bhaiya",
        "full_name": "Munna Bhaiya",
        "aadhaar_number": "123456789011",
        "zip": "110088",
        "gender": "M",
        "share_code": "6921",
        "face_score": -1,
        "raw_xml": "https://link-to-docs",
        "has_image": true,
        "address": {
            "loc": "Lehna Singh Market",
            "street": "",
            "house": "Flat No - 123",
            "po": "Mirzapur",
            "country": "India",
            "subdist": "Mirzapur",
            "vtc": "Mirzapur",
            "dist": "North Mirzapur",
            "state": "Uttar Pradesh"
        },
        "client_id": "aadhaar_v2_JlgixCkkkqinfMqtnThX",
        "zip_data": "https://link-to-zip",
        "profile_image": "base_64_image",
        "face_status": false,
        "dob": "1996-01-01"
    },
    "success": true,
    "message_code": "success",
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": null
}
```

But What I'm getting is object converted to string, so how should I eliminate This that **backward slash** from this to make it `jsonObject`?

```json
{
    \"data\": {
        \"care_of\": \"S/O: Kaleen Bhaiya\",
        \"full_name\": \"Munna Bhaiya\",
        \"aadhaar_number\": \"123456789011\",
        \"zip\": \"110088\",
        \"gender\": \"M\",
        \"share_code\": \"6921\",
        \"face_score\": \-1\,
        \"raw_xml\": \"https://link-to-docs\",
        \"has_image\": \true\,
        \"address\": \{
            \"loc\": \"Lehna Singh Market\",
            \"street\": "",
            \"house\": \"Flat No - 123\",
            \"po\": \"Mirzapur\",
            \"country\": \"India\",
            \"subdist\": \"Mirzapur",
            \"vtc\": \"Mirzapur\",
            \"dist\": \"North Mirzapur\",
            \"state\": \"Uttar Pradesh\"
        },
        \"client_id\": \"aadhaar_v2_JlgixCkkkqinfMqtnThX\",
        \"zip_data\": \"https://link-to-zip\",
        \"profile_image\": \"base_64_image\",
        \"face_status\": \false\,
        \"dob\": \"1996-01-01\"
    },\
    \"success\": \true\,
    \"message_code\": \"success\",
    \"status_code\": \200\,
    \"message\": \null\
}
```

Comment: Try `Gson().toJson(your_object)`

Comment: @Kartik What I want to know is how to pass the object by using Request body

Comment: What is your requirement? To pass the jsonObject as string or pass the jsonObject directly?

Comment: @Kartik to pass JsonObject Directly

Comment: Did you try `@Body` in a `@POST` request? Just pass this object as an `@Body` param and see if that works.

Comment: Tried but even that doesn't work it gives error, i'm really confused as i have to post an image to with the request i'm using Multi-Part so the rest thing i have to send as `@Part`  and not `@Body`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245545/discussion-between-kartik-and-rahul-pandey).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare a method in your RetrofitService:

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @POST("path")
    Call<ResponseBody> update(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
}
```

Next you need to create a RequestBody and Call object:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://somedomain.com").build();
    RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    
    String strRequestBody = "body";
    //use text/json for Json data string, or use text/plain for any other text
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/json"), bodyTextStringJsonValue);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitService.update(requestBody);
```